# ask for a shortcut problem

Tags: shortcut-keys, settings, shortcuts

I am using Ubuntu 11.10. Whenever I type Ctr+f in Chrome or Okular or Kile, the xTerm will appear instead of usually-expected "search bar". I have installed xbindkeys. It seems not that problem since the problem persists if I uninstall xbindkeys. Does anyone know what setting I should change? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First**
Check your shortcuts at System Settings > keyboard > shortcuts

**Second**
Install gconf-editor (`sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`), open it (press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and type `gconf-editor`.
Then go to Edit > Find and search for `Ctrl` (make sure to check "Search also in key names" and "Search also in key values")

**Third**

[xbindkeys](http://man.cx/xbindkeys%281%29) has caused trouble for others too, see [here](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/15605/ctrl-f-not-working-anywhere-solved/).
You said that you have tried to uninstall it, but have you purged it?

`sudo apt-get remove --purge xbindkeys`

Comment: Dear desgua, I checked. There is nothing special. At the Lauchers, to launch terminal is Ctrl+Alt+T, instead of Ctrl+f. I don't know the system relates Ctrl+f with launch terminal. Thanks.

Comment: Can you install "gconf-editor", then open it and search for ctrl+f?

Comment: Dear Desgua, I just installed gconf-editor. I looked through all items from searching Ctrl. I don't find the relation of Ctrl+f with opening xterminal. Thanks anyway. :-)

Comment: I removed xterm. In Chrome or Ocular, when I type Ctrl+f, nothing happens. I am expecting the searching bar.

Comment: xbindkeys has caused trouble for others too, see: http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/15605/ctrl-f-not-working-anywhere-solved/

Comment: Dear desgua, I did what you told me, purging xbindkeys. The problem persists.

Comment: Dear desgua, after purging xbindkeys and restarting my computer, the problem is solved. Thanks you very much for your patience and great help! :-)

Comment: I'm glad we fix it :-)